# How do I make my Image go above the Header

Tags: html, css, image, sass, css-position

Hello I want my profile photo / image go over the header area but.
As you can see it is getting cut off.

[image]

I tried playing around with the code and I got close I also made the position absolute but it messes up the flex size 2 (for the about me section).

So how can i fix this without messing up the flex 1 and flex 2?
Right now I am using Sass

http://lonestarwebandgraphics.com/

[image]

html

```
<div id="about-me" >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content-info p-2">
            <h1 class="section-title">About Me</h1>
            <p class="lead">Hello my name is Ruben Esquivel and my dad was a graphic designer so I grew up playing with 
                photoshop since I was a kid. For 10 years I worked as a remote graphic designer / web master running entire graphics department by myself providing mockups for getting sales and turning the mockups into print ready graphics to be printed.
                
                I am an expert in taking directions through phone or email and multi tasking multiple projects at once to meet the deadline. I can handle being under pressure and I am a master of hot keys so I can work fast when needed. 
                
                After working in the industry for 10 years I felt like I knew everything when it came to graphic design so I decided to learn web development because I love learning new things. I love coding and I love taking my web designs and creating beautiful eye catchy websites. To be honest I love both graphic design and coding, being able to take an idea and turn into a design or website is like creating magic for me.</p>

        </div>
        <div class="profile-pic">
            <img class="p-2" src="img/ruben-profile-pic_01.png" alt="Ruben Profile Photo" class="ruben-profile-photo">

        </div>
       
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS / SASS CODE

```
#about-me {
    // z-index: 50;
    // overflow: visible;
    // height: 100%;
    // background: red;
    margin-top: -3rem;
    position: relative;
    
    .container {
        // position: relative;
        display: flex;

        .content-info {
            flex: 2;
        }

        .profile-pic {
            flex: 1;
            margin-top: -5rem;
            // position: relative;
            // position: absolute;
            // right: 0;
            // z-index: 20;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Just try to provide the height of the image. Should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it gets cut off because you have `overflow: hidden` specified for `.container`.
An option would be to remove it and decrease a bit the padding of the image element, because it otherwise causes horizontal scrollbar to appear. A good idea might also be to use media queries for the padding, because width of the elements in the container is proportional to the resolution, but padding is not.

Comment: Thanks you were right! I forgot in my utilities file I had container: hidden so I added overflow: visible;  and it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should play around with z-index

```
.container{
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}
.profile-pic{
position:absolute;
z-index: 2;
top:-25px;
}
```

You can play around with the top element.